# Can I have a different changelist per each module in Android Studio?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, changelist

I have project with a few modules, each one with his own git repository.

When I am trying to commit changes to one of them, Android Studio automatically offers me to commit all changes in all modules with one commit message etc. I can manually uncheck other modules, but it is very inconvenient to do this each time and can cause human-factor errors.

So can I separate changes in each module to different changelist?
Or commit changes separately in any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create new changelist with different name, then move the file into the corresponding changelist.

Version Control - Local Changes - click the "+" icon to create new changelist
[image]

Comment: But you still need manually move each file to appropriate change list...